# Graphics bug after system updates Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: graphics, update-manager

Yesterday I made some system updates, and after that my ubuntu shows mixed colors around every new opened window. I tried to remove the latest update but it doesn't solve the problem. When I reboot the system, mixed colors disappears until the first suspend or hibernate. Here is an example of new opened window:

[image: "mixed color" border of settings]

Output of dpkg -l | grep nvidia:

```
 ii  nvidia-367                                  375.39-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 
                      amd64        Transitional package for nvidia-375
ii  nvidia-375                                  375.39-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 
                      amd64        NVIDIA binary driver - version 375.39
ii  nvidia-opencl-icd-367                       375.39-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
                       amd64        Transitional package for nvidia-opencl-icd-375
ii  nvidia-opencl-icd-375                       375.39-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
                       amd64        NVIDIA OpenCL ICD
ii  nvidia-prime                                0.8.2 
                                        amd64        Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                             361.42-0ubuntu1 
                       amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
```

video card:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
```

nvidia GeForce 930M

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `dpkg -l | grep nvidia` terminal command. And what is the adapter?

Comment: I have added the output. But which is the adapter that you think of?

Comment: I am asking what is the video card. Please do not post terminal output as a screenshot. Post it as text. This is a bug with the 375 driver on some adapters.

Comment: I made the changes

Comment: Any solution to this problem yet? I have the exact same issue. GeForce GTX 965 M.

Currently running this driver:

ii  nvidia-378                                 378.09-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.1                    amd64        NVIDIA binary driver - version 378.09  I can make the funny borders go away be restarting `unity`, but that causes other problems.

Comment: I changed the driver from 375.39 to 370.28. Under Software & Updates->Additional drivers . This looks like temporary solution. Do you know any better solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bug is also reported here:
https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/995750/linux/375-39-causes-corruption-of-window-decor-on-ubuntu-after-suspend-resume/

The next release should fix this problem.
The temporary fix described [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-375/+bug/1667158/comments/13) works for me:

```
echo -e '#!/bin/bash'"\n## This file (or a link to it) must be in the folder /lib/systemd/system-sleep/\n## Purpose: Kill compiz after system wakes up from sleep.\n## This will fix bad window borders caused by Nvidia driver 375.39.\nkill \$(ps -C compiz -o pid=)" | sudo tee /lib/systemd/system-sleep/fixbadborders
sudo chmod +x /lib/systemd/system-sleep/fixbadborders
```

To remove this script:

```
sudo rm /lib/systemd/system-sleep/fixbadborders
```